# How to detect the orientation of the subview of a class added on other class view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, orientation

I want to detect the orientation(i.e Landscape or portrait) of the subview of the class which I have added on other class view controller. In other words, I have added a subview of the class viewcontroller to the other class view controller. and now I want to detect the orientation of that view.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
subViewController.interfaceOrientation
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a clean interface, you could create a category class for UIApplication and return interfaceOrientation on these lines:

`- (UIInterfaceOrientation)my_interfaceOrientation {
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &interfaceOrientationKey) intValue];
}`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `viewController.interfaceOrientation` doesn't seem to work quite well, you probably should better go with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` assuming that you don't do any "dirty" hacks on the user interface!